# Evitar que se agregue el mismo registro en la tabla detalle

Tags: php, jquery

Necesito evitar que se agregue el mismo registro en la tabla detalle.. ¿Habra una forma simple de poder realizar esto? Lo que estoy pensando es recorrer la tabla con .each en jquery y alertar que el articulo esta en la tabla , pero lo hice y no hace nada

// Funcion js para agregar al detalle

```
function agregar(idarticulos,nombre_arti,marca_arti,modelo_arti){
   if (idarticulos!="")
   {
    
    let fila='<tr class="item id="fila'+cont+'">'+
        '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" 
        '<td><input type="hidden"  class="item" name="idarticulos[]" value='+idarticulos+'>'+nombre_arti+'</td>'+
        '<td><input type="hidden" class="item" name="marca" value='+marca_arti+'>'+marca_arti+'</td>'+
        '<td><input type="hidden" class="item" name="modelo"+
        
        '</tr>';
 $ (".item").each(function(i){
   if(i==1){
    alert("el articulo esta en la tabla");
     return false;
     }else{
        cont++;
        detalles=detalles+1;
        $('#detalles').append(fila);
        }
      }else{
      alert("error")
      }
       }
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. Explica un poco el contexto. ¿Hay una tabla ya con datos y se agregan otros? ¿Por qué no controlas los duplicados cuando generas los datos?

Comment: @A.Cedano la tabla de arriba se carga con los datos que se encuentran en una tabla de la base de datos y la de abajo "la llamaremos detalles" se carga cuando selecciono un articulo de la tabla de arriba, lo que quiero es que que al seleccionar el "conmutador" y este en la tabla de abajo, me alerte "este articulo fue seleccionado, intente con otro"

Comment: Podrías por ejemplo desactivar en la tabla de arriba la posibilidad de que ese elemento sea seleccionado de nuevo cuando esté en la tabla de abajo. O irlos intercambiando entre tablas... Es decir, si lo seleccionas arriba pasa abajo y viceversa (esto ya depende del contexto). En cualquier caso, no tienes por qué recorrer la tabla cada vez.

Comment: @A.Cedano Eso es lo que estoy buscando hacer, como hago para que al tener selecciona 1 en en la tabla de abajo , no poder seleccionar 1 en la tabla de arriba de nuevo

Comment: Pues ya te sugerí dos posibilidades: 1. Desactivar en la tabla de arriba; 2. Intercambiar entre tablas, o sea, cuando presiones `+` que ese elemento pase de la tabla de arriba a la de abajo y cuando presiones `x` que pase de nuevo a la tabla de arriba. Elige lo que sea mejor según tu contexto. Puede que haya otras posibilidades, pero para este tipo de cosas es importante conocer el contexto, por ejemplo, se ve que hay un control de `Stock` por lo que es probable que este código haya que incorporarlo a una lógica que controle la cantidad en existencia, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que primero estás generando el HTML y después intentas verificar si ya existe el ID en la tabla.

La forma correcta de realizar esa validación es tomar el valor de todos los campos con nombre `idarticulos[]` y compararlos con el ID recibido; sin embargo, el método [$.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) recorre los valores y realiza la actividad dentro de una función anónima, lo que impide romper el ciclo, ya sea con `break` o `return`, por lo que se debe crear una variable para marcar cuando se encuentre un ID repetido.

```
function agregarDetalle(idarticulos, nombre_arti, marca_arti, modelo_arti, codigo_arti, stock, id) {
    // Primero realiza las validaciones necesarias
    if(idarticulos == '') {
        alert('Error: No se proporcionó ID de artículo');
        return false;
    }
    // Crea una variable para saber si está repetido
    let repetido = false;
    // Recorre los campos de ID para verificar si ya existe
    $('.item [name="idarticulos[]"]').each(function(i) {
        if($(this).val() == idarticulos) {
            // Ya existe en la tabla
            // No se puede romper el ciclo, solo marcar como repetido
            repetido = true;
        }
    });
    if(repetido) {
        alert('Error: El artículo ya está en la tabla.');
        return false;
    }
    let cantidad=1;
    let subtotal = cantidad;
    let fila = '<tr class="item id="fila'+cont+'">'+
            '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="eliminarDetalle('+cont+')">X</button</td>'+
            '<td><input type="hidden"  class="item" name="idarticulos[]" value='+idarticulos+'>'+nombre_arti+'</td>'+
            '<td><input type="hidden" class="item" name="marca" value='+marca_arti+'>'+marca_arti+'</td>'+
            '<td><input type="hidden" class="item" name="modelo" value='+modelo_arti+'>'+modelo_arti+'</td>'+
            '<td><input type="hidden" class="item" name="codigo" value='+codigo_arti+'>'+codigo_arti+'</td>'+
            '<td><input type="hidden" class="item" name="stock" value='+stock+'>'+stock+'</td>'+
            '<td><input type="number"  name="cantidad[]" id="cantidad[]" value="'+cantidad+'"></td>'+
            '<td><span name="subtotal" id="subtotal'+cont+'">'+subtotal+'</span></td>'+
            
            '</tr>';
    cont ++;
    detalles = detalles + 1;
    $('#detalles').append(fila);
    modificarSubtotales();
}
```

Por otra parte, creo que sería más conveniente mejorar la experiencia del usuario y, cuando se agregue un producto repetido, incrementar la cantidad en vez de mostrar mensaje de error, por ejemplo:

```
    // Crea una variable para saber si está repetido
    let repetido = false;
    // Recorre los campos de ID para verificar si ya existe
    $('.item [name="idarticulos[]"]').each(function(i) {
        if($(this).val() == idarticulos) {
            // Ya existe en la tabla
            repetido = true;
            // Obtener TR de este elemento para actualizar otros datos
            let tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            // Obtener campo de cantidad de esta fila
            let cant = $(tr).find('[name="cantidad[]"]');
            // Obtener valor
            cantidad = parseInt($(cant).val()) || 0;
            // Actualizar cantidad en campo
            $(cant).val(cantidad + 1);
            // ¿Es necesario actualizar más datos?
            // Ya tienes el ejemplo, inténtalo
        }
    });
    if(repetido) {
        // ¿Es necesario realizar otros cálculos?
        modificarSubtotales();
        return false;
    }
```